# How to add more than one CUDA gencode using modern CMAKE (per target)?

Tags: cmake, compilation, cuda

I'm unable to get modern cmake (per target) to set **more than one** CUDA gencode flag.

CMake example:

```
target_compile_options(myHeaderLib INTERFACE                        
                        $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:-gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50>
                        $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:-gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52>
                        $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:-gencode arch=compute_53,code=sm_53>
                        $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:-gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60>
                        $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:-gencode arch=compute_62,code=sm_62>
                        )
```

This will output:

```
... -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 arch=compute_53,code=sm_53
```

But what is needed is:

```
... -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50  -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52  -gencode arch=compute_53,code=sm_53 ...
```

And NO just **settings the ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} is not a robust solution** (that's not how modern CMAKE should be done).

Comment: It smells like space-separated values in the generator expressions do not work well. Try to **separate** `-gencode` and `arch=` options into their own generator expressions.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not 100% how you mean, but I tried:
target_compile_options(myHeaderLib INTERFACE                        
                        $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:-gencode>
                        $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:arch=compute_50,code=sm_50>
                        $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:-gencode>
                        $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:arch=compute_52,code=sm_52>
                        )
To no avail : /

Could you clarify how you mean? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, so this:
target_compile_options(myHeaderLib INTERFACE $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:-gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50>)
target_compile_options(myHeaderLib INTERFACE $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:-gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52>)

Produces:
-gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 arch=compute_52,code=sm_52

Whic is incorrect :/

Comment: Well, so generator expressions works correctly. What is wrong, that is a CMake behavior to "**de-duplicate**" options. They have a [bugreport](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/15826), which has been resolved in [3.12 version](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/target_compile_options.html) by adding construction `"SHELL:-gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50"`. But I cannot imagine how to use it with generator expressions... (Yes, I know that generator expressions are crucial for you).

Comment: @Tsyvarev, using the SHELL: syntax created correct behaviour in this case.

ex:

target_compile_options(myHeaderLib INTERFACE "SHELL:-gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50")                        
target_compile_options(myHeaderLib INTERFACE "SHELL:-gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52")                        

NVCC does not pass the flags to the CXX compiler so the generator expression syntax $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>: .... > appears unecessary in this case(?).

Comment: I have added my answer **without** notion of *generator expressions*. I am not very familiar with CUDA, but as far as I remember a construction `$<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>: .... >` is needed when you want to combine "normal" `.cpp` files with CUDA ones (`.cu`) in a single executable/library. So non-CUDA sources won't get `nvcc` options.

Comment: Yes is suppose when you mix things:


   add_executable(myApp  host_code.cpp mixed_code.cu)
   target_link_libraries(myApp myHeaderLib)

Above would cause issues wouldn't it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of CMake "**de-duplication**" strategy for the compile options.

With `target_compile_options` you create correct option's list

```
-gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50  -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 ...
```

but CMake removes all `-gencode` except the first one:

```
-gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 ...
```

There is [bugreport](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/15826) about needs to disable CMake "de-duplication" in some cases, and it has been resolved in [3.12 version](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/target_compile_options.html) by adding `SHELL:` construction.

Since CMake 3.12 this should work:

```
target_compile_options(myHeaderLib INTERFACE
   "SHELL:-gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50"
   "SHELL:-gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52"
)
```

---

#### How `SHELL:` works

First, placing combined options into double quotes prevents CMake to "de-duplicate" common options: CMake sees different strings

```
-gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50
-gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52
```

and doesn't think of them as a duplicated.

Then, a construction `SHELL` explains CMake that a string within given double quotes is needed to be splitted into separate command line options. But this splitting is performed **after** "de-duplication" stage, so repeated `-gencode` from different `SHELL:` strings are not removed.

Comment: It's not perfect but I think this is the best solution at the moment. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps could tell if its possible to mix $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>: ...> and SHELL: for a more robust solution?

Comment: Hm, have you tried simply `"$<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:SHELL:-gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50>"`? At this moment I have no new CMake available for test that. Actually, I thought that every *generator expression* should be transformed into a **single string**. May be, `COMPILE_LANGUAGE` expression is evaluated *immediately*, so CMake is able to split its content into separate arguments. If so, CMake should preserve  surrounding `""`, and everything should work in your case.

Comment: Yes, when I do that the de-duplication issues persists.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while. But recently I filed an issue and it turns out generators can also works perfectly. The trick to combine "SHELL:" with generators is to surround generators with double quotes.

Here's the [link](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/19502) where the maintainer of cmake points out my mistake. Hope this helps others in the future.

```
target_compile_options(foo PRIVATE
  "$<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:SHELL:-gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60>"
  )
target_compile_options(foo PRIVATE
  "$<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:SHELL:-gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50>"
  )
```